# I removed /etc/acpache2, how do I put back? (OSX)

Tags: macos, apache2

Ok, so I was having some issues getting rails setup and I'm very new to this.  I decided in the end to delete the apache2 folder in /etc as I thought that was created by the passenger-install-apache2-module, but apparently thats not so.

So... now I installed rvm, installed ruby, installed passenger, ran the `rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module` command and then went to edit the config file... but its not there.

So I clearly made a mistake deleting that.  How do I put it back?  More importantly, did I screw anything up?

---

**Update for solution:**

What I ended up doing was Archive and Install from the OSX DVD (I'm using snow leopard so I had to do this manually).  I probably could have used Pacifist to just install apache, not sure if thats possible but found out about it after I did the archive install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try re-installing apache2.

Comment: but apache seems to be working fine, when I go to system preferences > sharing, web sharing still seems to be working (visiting my IP shows the "It works" page)

Comment: Have you restarted apache since nuking the directory? The files are read only when Apache starts, so removing them while it's running won't have any effect until you restart it.

Comment: Apache will work until you try restarting the service or the machine. Try restarting the service or machine and see what happens. At that point you are probably going to need to reinstall apache2.

Comment: running sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart, gave me an error /usr/sbin/apachectl: line 82: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument, I stopped it and tried to start it again but wouldn't work.  However, turning websharing on still works... weird!

Comment: Try this instead apachectl -k restart, this will kill open processes.

Comment: What linux distrobution is your server running? Oh wait, or are you running osx? You have a tag for osx.

Comment: yup, on osx.  Btw, running sudo apachectl -k restart gave me this, httpd: Could not open configuration file /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: No such file or directory, so i definitely screwed things up by deleting that directory

Comment: Correct, you did. =P A simple google search for isntalling apache2 on osx gives you a few results on how to install with tutorials. GL and let me know if this helps solve your issue.

Comment: not a problem, hope it works. Accept the answer as a solution if it works. I want my rep! =)

Comment: will do.. im not having any luck finding info on installing apache on snow leopard, all the links just say that it comes built in!

Comment: I am not familiar with osx, however i found this link. http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20051214031718251   Goto the very bottom of that page almost the last comment. There is a guide there that might help you. The comment was made by TÃ©tonne, you will only need to do the apache parts. Keep looking if you dont like this guide, there may be much better ones.

Comment: thanks for the link, it doesn't seem to put the /etc/apache2 directory back though :'(

Comment: You may have better luck posting a howto question in an osx forum somewhere. I saw where you created a question here and it got quickly deleted, lol. good luck.

Comment: yeah i reposted that question hehe, I'll try posting in an osx forum too and searching for some more info.  Thanks a lot!  I'll be sure to accept this answer if re-installing works.

Comment: You actually might find that http://superuser.com/ will give you better results. Try posting there and see what happens.